# HTAccess using a UIWebView

Tags: ios, .htaccess, uiwebview

I am trying to create an app that saves UIWebView passwords, specifically password protected htaccess. Right now I am sending the username and password in the URL, but this is insecure and causes problems when used on a non-htaccess webpage.

How can I determine if a webpage uses htaccess, and then authenticate for it?
E: I forgot to specify, I am developing for a universal iPhone/iPad app.

Comment: Try using the header to detect that.

Comment: After reading more information about headers and how htaccess works, I realized that my question was unintelligent, and showed a lack of research. I apologize for wasting your time, and I thank you for your help.